# Logging to rake's trace log

Tags: ruby, rake

Is it possible to print custom messages to the output of `rake --trace`?

Answer (score 0):

The cheap and nasty way (for anyone reading) is to run rake with the --verbose option, then use the standard `puts` Ruby function to write out your debug line.

But it is nasty.

Comment: Define "nasty" please. If something has negative side-effects, please indicate them.

Comment: Apologies for the term. I say nasty because in general terms if you want to add logging into an app/script you should attempt to use a more complete logging solution, which you can then control the logging abilities (modes to turn logging on or off based on configuration).

There's no really any side-effects as such.

Comment: Then I'd explain it just like that in the answe